# No duplicate from java string array selection

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I'm trying to randomly select multiple words from an array with no duplicates. This is what is have so far

```
final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            int index2 = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            int index3 = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            System.out.println("Law:" + Laws[index] + "," + Laws[index2] + "," + Laws[index3]);
```

I want to be able to get no duplicate words someone told me to use a for loop to do it.

```
final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            System.out.println("Law:" + Laws[index]);
            }
```

but when I use the for loop I get the answer on multiple lines rather then 1 line.

I want it to come out like

"Law: x, x"

rather than

"Law:x

Law:x"

or how ever many times I do the loop

can anyone help me fix this problem ?

Comment: use `System.out.print()`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `print()` instead of `println()`. `print()` will write it out to standard output without the newline character (`\n`) at the end whereas `println()` will.

For example:

```
System.out.println("test1");
System.out.println("test2");
System.out.println("-------");
System.out.print("test3");
System.out.print("test4");
```

will output

```
test1
test2
-------
test3test4
```

Answer (score 0):

So in my experience what you are looking for is a HashSet, they do not allow unique values so my advice would be to use something like this

```
 final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
        Random random = new Random();
        String fullString = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length)+1; //otherwise the final string index wont be accessed
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
          set.add(al[i]);
        }
        for (String str : set) 
        {
            fullString = fullString + " " + str;
        }
        System.out.println("Law: " + fullString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Many MANY ways to get that... I suggest to use Collections since the have methods for it:

```
String[] alphabet = { "A", "E", "I", "O", "U" };
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(alphabet));
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        System.out.print("list: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(0));
            list.remove(0);
            Collections.shuffle(list);
        }
```

This prints in the Terminal: `list: IUAEO`.

The Keys:

> I want it to come out like "Law: x, x" rather than  "Law:x Law:x"....

Don't use `println` instead use `print`

> ....I want to be able to get no duplicate words someone told me to use
>   a for loop to do it.

Remove the element of the list as soon as you print it, with `Random` you can not avoid a duplicate number easily.